# Contact charging of glass with silk

Tags: electrostatics

When I was rubbing glass with silk. I found only some glasses are getting charged positively not all. I didn't understood the reason. For example, I took glass beaker and glass tube the former is getting charged while rubbing with silk but latter didn't get charged at all.

Comment: Perhaps the glass rod is greasy, try to clean up both glass things with soap and hot water and then try rubbing each with new, ungreased piece of silk.

Comment: Both the glasses where cleaned properly with said and water.

Answer (score 0):

It may be dirty but it also might well be a surface layer of moisture on the glass rod and/or silk.
That surface layer of moisture is a very good conductor of charge in the realm of electrostatics demonstrations/experiments.

Try drying the glassware and silk for a few minutes using a fan heater.